# how to cross compile CUPS on ARM in Linux environment?

Tags: linux, printing, arm, cups, network-printers

I am new in embedded systems and I am sorry for not knowing a more about
embedded systems and this is my first project.

I am also trying to add a USB printer support in Linux Kernel ver 2.6.30.

I want to cross compile CUPS ver 1.6.2 for ARM board.

So Can you please suggest some steps to cross-compile CUPS on Linux.

Thanks in advance for your suggestions.